# Are there still "item lists" at Nooks'?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

In the first Animal Crossing there was a special feature to encourage visiting friend's towns; each town had an item rotation (A B or C I think), and certain items outside of your item rotation would be very hard to find as Nook's either wouldn't sell them or they'd only show as showcase items or something.

Is New Leaf similar? If so, how does that work? How do I know which set of items my Nooks' has?

Answer (score 2):

This feature was not included in New Leaf. Instead, they have a shop called Re-Tail which is essentially a flea market where you can put your own items for your villagers and friends to purchase.